# Why does IntelliSense think a value from my dictionary is a dynamic?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamic, intellisense

Say i have the following method:

```
private void something()
{
    string text = "This is obviously a string";
    dynamic pietje = Guid.NewGuid();

    var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
    dict.Add(pietje, text);

    var someText = dict[pietje];
}
```

The image below shows IntelliSense still thinks it is a dynamic even though i do not see how this could be anything other than a string (or null)
[image]

Am I missing a setting or is there something preventing IntelliSense from knowing `someText` should be a string? I might be leaning on IntelliSense a bit too much, but it gets quite difficult for some objects to manually type the entire method or property name correctly.

So what is the reason for this? And is there something I can do to resolve this?

obviously I could fix it in many ways:

```
string someText = dict[pietje];
var someText = dict[(Guid)pietje];
var someText = dict[pietje] as string;
```

etc.
But that is not the point nor what I want.

Comment: Why is `pietje` dynamic instead of a `Guid`?

Comment: You know that decision for the dynamic variables are taken at runtime....not compile time. use var instead :)

Comment: Hover the ```dict``` in ```var dict```. Maybe your compiler is trying to outsmart you by defining the dict to be something like ```Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>``` because of the fact you're adding a dynamic.

Comment: This is just an example, I get my key to my dictionary as a dynamic value (long story). And to illustrate my point in easy to understand code I simplified it to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue crops up in many scenarios. Classic question in SO:

```
public string Foo(string fooable) { .... }

dynamic fooable = "whatever";
var whyAmIDynamic = Foo(fooable);
```

Huh? Why is `wyAmIDynamic` `dynamic`?!? The compiler should know that `wyAmIDynamic` is `string`, shouldn't it?

Yes, but then someone else comes along and writes the following:

```
public int Foo(int fooable) { .... } //a new overload of Foo
```

And now, what should `Foo(fooable)` return? `dynamic` seems to be the only reasonable option; a method call involving a `dynamic` argument can't be resolved until runtime.

In your specific case, the compiler has no reason not to believe that someone might come along and implement the following absurd overload to `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
public int this[string key] { ... }
```

Does this overload make any sense? No. Is it the compilers business to figure out if it makes sense? No. Is it *legal*? Yes, therefore the indexer returns a `dynamic` variable.

Comment: Never looked at it like this, indeed a problem would arrive when someone were to overload a method like that. thanks :)

Comment: Still, overloads can be resolved on compile time. There is just a language rule about dynamics.

Comment: That is my point: nothing can be resolved because it is dynamic. Otherwise it could have, even if you add X methods.

Answer (score 3):

Because `pietje` is `dynamic`, the result of the execution of `var someText = dict[pietje];` is determined on runtime. Until that time, the correctness and outcome of that call is unknown, hence `dynamic`.

I guess you meant to use `var` here, since you know the type of `pietje` on beforehand.

---

As said in a comment: You go by the simple rule that **all dynamic evaluations are done on runtime**. You can type in an invalid field name and still let it compile.

Comment: This is just an example, I get my key to my dictionary as a dynamic value (long story). And to illustrate my point in easy to understand code I simplified it to this.

But the call can only have 3 outputs: Exception, null or string. there is no need to have the resulting object to be a dynamic.

Comment: You go by the simple rule that **all dynamic evaluations are done on runtime**. You can type in an invalid field name and still let it compile.

Comment: yes I knew that all dynamic evaluations are done on runtime but somehow it seemed so trivial to do it when trying to get a value from something 'fixed' like a dictionary. but i get it now. bit of a 'duh' moment :P

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the Dictionary to be of type `Dictionary<Guid, string>`. When you try to read, you're using a `dynamic` as the key for the dictionary, not even knowing if this is would be a valid statement.

There's a relative easy way of fixing this issue:

**Address the key in the dictionary with the same type as the declaration**

```
string text = "This is obviously a string";
dynamic pietje = Guid.NewGuid();

var dict = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
dict.Add(pietje, text);

var someText = dict[(Guid)pietje];
//Of course you could go about casting this in numerous ways
```

Comment: Yes I know (added this example to my question), it was not exactly what I was looking for. sorry if i was unclear.